# pandas join dataframes based on the TOP 1 result of an ordered list of matching records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with all available options for sale:

```
options = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  'Price':[1,3,6,4], 
                  'Size':[12,32,44,68], 
                  'Content':[10,8,22,20]}
```

And a list of needs:

```
criteria = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'],
                  'MinSize':[8,20,12,40], 
                  'MinContent':[18,6,21,4]}
```

I need to get the **lowest price** from the options that meets the minimum criteria, resulting in:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'],
                  'MinSize':[8,20,12,40], 
                  'MinContent':[18,6,21,4],
                  'MatchingOption':['d','b','c','d']}
```

This would be the equivalent of a `TOP 1 WHERE Content >= MinContent AND Size >= MinSize ORDER BY Price ASC` in SQL.

How do I join dataframes based on the TOP 1 result of an ordered list of matching records?

Comment: why is d4 -> c and not d?

Comment: That was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is large and require fast execution time, here is a **version with all vectorized operations** for better system performance:

Use [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (cross merge) + [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) + [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`idxmin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html):

```
# cross merge and filter with .query()
legitimate_matches =  criteria.merge(options, how='cross').query('(Size >= MinSize) & (Content >= MinContent)')

# get lowest price entries by .groupby() + .idxmin()
best_matches = legitimate_matches.loc[legitimate_matches.groupby('Customer')['Price'].idxmin()]
```

If your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (December 2020 version) and does not support merge with `how='cross'`, you can use:

```
# cross merge and filter with .query()
legitimate_matches = criteria.assign(key=1).merge(options.assign(key=1), on='key').query('(Size >= MinSize) & (Content >= MinContent)') 

# get lowest price entries by .groupby() + .idxmin()
best_matches = legitimate_matches.loc[legitimate_matches.groupby('Customer')['Price'].idxmin()]
```

**Result:**

```
print(best_matches)

   Customer  MinSize  MinContent Name  Price  Size  Content
3        a1        8          18    d      4    68       20
5        b2       20           6    b      3    32        8
10       c3       12          21    c      6    44       22
15       d4       40           4    d      4    68       20
```

You can then remove unnecessary columns and rename column `Name` to `MatchingOption`.

```
final_result = best_matches[['Customer', 'MinSize', 'MinContent', 'Name']].rename({'Name': 'MatchingOption'}, axis=1)
```

**Final result:**

```
print(final_result)

   Customer  MinSize  MinContent MatchingOption
3        a1        8          18              d
5        b2       20           6              b
10       c3       12          21              c
15       d4       40           4              d
```

Comment: All three of the answers are good, but this has the logic closest to the SQL example (joining and top 1) referenced in my question and is also very readable. Also, the intent of getting the matching option was then to merge the dataframes, which this does. I wish I could mark 3 correct answers...

Comment: @user15741  You got very good solution selection criteria.  You also know well what you your works need.  Well done!  Seldom seen such logical question asker.  You are surely one of the best I seen!    Happy programming!

Answer (score 2):

for each row in `criteria`, filter out the `options` for `Size>=MinSize` and `Content>=MinContent`, then just sort `Price` column and take the first value for `Name`, assign the resulting series back to the new column for criteria dataframe:

```py
result=(criteria.assign(MatchingOption=criteria
                 .apply(lambda x: 
                        options[(options['Size'].ge(x['MinSize']))
                        & (options['Content'].ge(x['MinContent']))]
                        .sort_values('Price').iloc[0]['Name'],
                        axis=1))
 )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  Customer  MinSize  MinContent MatchingOption
0       a1        8          18              d
1       b2       20           6              b
2       c3       12          21              c
3       d4       40           4              d
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option: you can use `.idxmin()`:

```py
criteria["MatchingOption"] = criteria.apply(
    lambda x: options.loc[
        options.loc[
            (options["Size"] >= x["MinSize"])
            & (options["Content"] >= x["MinContent"]),
            "Price",
        ].idxmin(),
        "Name",
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Prints:

```
  Customer  MinSize  MinContent MatchingOption
0       a1        8          18              d
1       b2       20           6              b
2       c3       12          21              c
3       d4       40           4              d
```

Comment: Is idxmin() a faster method than sort_values?

Comment: @user15741 `idxmin()` is O(n), `sort_values()` is O(n log n). But to be sure, benchmark it.